# document.write causes strange behavior with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**[Problem]**

Disappearing other JS contents(facebook Like button) on same page with following JS.
(Only Google Chrome)
This bug is caused by following JS.

**[Question]**

Why the bug happened? 
And this solution is right?
If you have any idea, could you tell me?

I tried to make "text" has document.write() part without document.open() and document.close().
But, it didn't cause disappearing other JS contents.

**[Target Code]**

This javascript is executed in iframe.
Then, the iframes will be output in iframe.

```
View.prototype.make_iframe = function(id, text) {
  var doc, iframe, isIE;
  iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.width = 0;
  iframe.height = 0;
  iframe.id = id;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
  /* Problem part start */
  doc.write("<html><head></head><body>");
  doc.write(text);
  doc.write("</body></html>");
  /* Problem part end */
};


 View.prototype.get_tag_files = function(dir, fname, data, make_iframe) {
  var xmlObj;
  xmlObj = null;
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmlObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
    xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlObj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var i, item, tag, text, _i, _len;
    if (xmlObj.readyState === 4 && xmlObj.status === 200) {
      text = xmlObj.responseText;
      tag = new Tag(data, text);
      tag.replace();
      return make_iframe(fname, tag.get_tag());
    }
  };
  xmlObj.open("GET", dir + fname, true);
  return xmlObj.send(null);
};
```

**[Solution]**

```
  /* target part */
  doc.write("<html><head></head><body>");
  doc.write(text);
  doc.write("</body></html>");

  ==>

  /* replaced target part */
  isIE = /MSIE/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
  if (!isIE) {
    doc.clear();
    doc.open;
  }
  doc.write("<html><head></head><body>");
  doc.write(text);
  doc.write("</body></html>");
  if (!isIE) {
    return doc.close();
  } else {
    return;
  }
```

---

**To : First commenter**

Thank you for your response.

I tried to use appendChild function.
But, it doesn't work.
"text" variable has some HTML and JS tags which get data from other servers.
When I used appendChild instead of document.write function,
the tags can't communicate other server via network.
I don't know the cause.

This code is generated by coffee script compiler.
And coffee script code has the view class, so the code has prototype.
Original code(coffee script) is following one.

```
Tag = require("../src/tag").Tag

class View
    constructor: (data) ->
        @validated = data
        @viewid = "product"

    make_iframe: (id,text) ->
        iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
        iframe.width = 0
        iframe.height = 0
        iframe.id = id
        document.body.appendChild(iframe)
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document
        isIE = /MSIE/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)

        if !isIE
            doc.clear()
            doc.open
        doc.write("<html><head></head><body>")
        doc.write(text)
        doc.write("</body></html>")
        if !isIE
            return doc.close()
        else
            return

    get_tag_files: (dir,fname,data,make_iframe) ->
        xmlObj = null
        if window.ActiveXObject
            xmlObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        else
            xmlObj = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xmlObj.onreadystatechange = ->
            if xmlObj.readyState == 4 && xmlObj.status == 200
                text = xmlObj.responseText
                tag = new Tag(data, text)
                tag.replace()
                make_iframe(fname,tag.get_tag())
            xmlObj.open("GET", dir+fname, true)
            xmlObj.send(null)

    output_tags: (tags, path) ->
        for tag in tags
            @get_tag_files(path, tag, @validated, @make_iframe)

        return """
               """

exports.View = View
```

Comment: Use JS embedded methods for node creation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild  Why you use `prototype`?